# issue using JQuery unsafe inline and CSP

Tags: jquery, nonce

I'm using JQuery and i'm trying to implement Content Security Policy directives on my webpage.

I'm getting the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'nonce-c20t41c7-73c6-4bf9-fde8-24a7b35t5f71'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-KAcpKskREkEQf5B3mhDTonpPg34XnzaUC5IoBrOUrwY='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Basically, it adds an inline script tag to the DOM, and violates the CSP.

I do not want to use `unsafe-inline`. Is there any other way to circumvent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of error we can avoid by  following methods:

1)Remove all form tags present in the project.
2)Remove all inline and internal styles from the page.
3)Remove all inline styles written from the js pages.